# How to push a downloaded Github Repo back?

Tags: github

I have a Blog Project on Github and downloaded the Project locally to my computer by hitting the Download button on the left. I've committed some changes now locally and want to push the files back to the same Repo. How can I push the files back to the active repo?

Comment: anyone knows some helpful links or videos to watch?

Comment: I thought I could just download the project locally do some CSS changes and push the changes back with one command or so lol

Comment: You will need to use git. This is a good reference how to incorporate your changes back https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork

Comment: Thanks so much, man. So it is possible to do it.

Comment: Just checked. I haven't forked it tho. I've downloaded it locally.